# Wordpress posts custom social meta tag

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

is there any way to have custom meta tags for posts like og:url
all i found dont have og:url
can you suggest something?

I tried to modify a simple plugin but it is messy
[plugin link](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-open-graph.1.5.zip)

I don't know what to do

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code snippet you tried to use, otherwise this post may be closed as it doesn't meet the StackOverflow question guidelines. Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The og:url should always be equal to the canonical URL. Every good OG plugin should take this into account.

**Answer:** change the canonical URL of the post and the og:url will change as well. If not, try a different plugin. It should work.